# Why do I see a (simplified) second flavor of Ubuntu Graphical Desktop after switching to startx?

Tags: desktop-environments

I need some insight information from Ubuntu guru on this.

With a normal installation of Ubuntu 22.04, I see graphical desktop like this (A1):

[image: A1. normal desktop]

There is a nice left-docking taskbar showing what applications are running.

Clicking the Applications button at lower left, I see this (A2):

[image]

Now, I try to tweak Ubuntu into "text login behavior", by executing this command:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Then, reboot Ubuntu, and the system stay at white-text-on-black-background text login screen, and I login in then try to execute `startx`.

[image: Ubuntu text login to startx]

This time, I see B1.1 and B1.2 .

[image: B1.1]

[image: B1.2]

Click top-left corner [Activities], I see B2.1, then click [Show Applications], I see B2.2:

[image: B2.1]

[image: B2.2]

Apparently, B series screen is different from A1 and A2.

I'd like to ask:

(1) Why are they different?

(2) Using the "text-login + startx" method, can I achieve the same Desktop as A1?